# ASP.Net WebForms Routing Single Route for Multiple Destinations

Tags: asp.net, webforms, routes

I am looking into setting database routing up for a new website I plan to create. I have been looking at the following tutorial with regards to utilising friendlyUrls from a database:

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-45/getting-started-with-aspnet-45-web-forms/url-routing

However, I would like to use the same route structure for multiple entities. Meaning:

mysite.com/{PlayerName} goes to player.aspx
mysite.com/{TeamName} goes to team.aspx
… and so on …

Could somebody point in the right direction of achieving this with asp.net. Is it possible using the built in routing engine, or should I be looking to code my own HTTPModule for this?

Thanks
David

Comment: How would the routing know if `foo` is a team or a player in `mysite.com/foo`? On the page you linked to it says among other things that `{language}{country}/{action}` is not valid because routing cannot know where the language ends and the country starts. Your idea has the same problem.

Comment: That is not possible using System.Web.Routing - the structure of the URL will look identical to the routing engine, so how will it know what type of entity the URL refers to ? Why can't you use *mysite.com/teams/{teamname}* and *mysite.com/players/{playername}* instead ?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I was hoping to be able to provide the same simple URL structure for teams and players in order to keep it short and simple. 

I was thinking it may have been possible to implement my own HTTP module that maybe sits in front of the routing engine so that:

User navigates to: mysite.com/JoeBloggs,
My HTTP Module then does a db lookup and then some kind of server.transfer to: mysite.com/players/JoeBloggs,
URL Routing then handles the mysite.com/players/{playername} route accordingly. 

However, this sounds to be over complicating this issue?

Comment: What is your solution if playername and teamname are equal? If you want to make a database lookup for each request from the client the performance of your web app goes down. It will be fired for all resources -for images, css, js, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write two [constraints](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/controllers-and-routing/creating-a-custom-route-constraint-cs) which return boolean whether segment is a team or not / a player or not.

```
public class IsTeamConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match
        (
            HttpContextBase httpContext, 
            Route route, 
            string parameterName, 
            RouteValueDictionary values, 
            RouteDirection routeDirection
        )
    {
        return SomeService.IsTeam(values["teamName"]);
    }
}

public class IsPlayerConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match
        (
            HttpContextBase httpContext, 
            Route route, 
            string parameterName, 
            RouteValueDictionary values, 
            RouteDirection routeDirection
        )
    {
        return SomeService.IsPlayer(values["playerName"]);
    }
}
```

Set constraint in page route.

```
void RegisterCustomRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "Team",
        "{teamName}",
        "~/Team.aspx",
        false,
        null,
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "isTeam", new IsTeamConstraint() } }
    );
    routes.MapPageRoute(
        "Player",
        "{playerName}",
        "~/Player.aspx",
        false,
        null,
        new RouteValueDictionary { { "isPlayer", new IsPlayerConstraint() } }
    );
}
```

Now when a page is requested registered page routes will use constraint to check that the route is valid and execute page if it is.

I haven't tried this in ASP.Net Forms but I've applications running with constraints developed in ASP.Net MVC. Both type of application (Forms and MVC) shared common routing logic.

Comment: I tested this in web forms and working out of the box.

Comment: Hi, apologies, I think the bounty was already awarded, but I must say this seems a much better approach. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Comment: Thank you and that is fine, I just answered this question 2 days ago and curious to know how it goes with real implementation so I did it today :-)

Comment: @Mihir , @DavidReid what will be the `SomeService.Isplayer` or  `SomeService.IsTeam` in this context

Comment: @Webruster The logic which checks name that it is a player or team. Assuming that the logic is simply encapsulated in a service nothing else. You can also write logic in the constraint class. I prefer to segregate it in services.

Comment: @Mihir for better understanding please have a look at this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40317924/routing-based-on-same-parameters-pattern-and-different-pages-in-web-forms)

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why so many people say that this cannot be done with routing - maybe I'm not getting something, but the same logic that apparently makes the accepted answer a valid option should be perfectly applicable to a custom route handler, e.g. IRouteHandler or something derived from System.Web.Routing.RouteBase.

You can add "managers" to your RouteCollection (RouteTable.Routes) in the manner of:

```
routes.Add("MyRoutName", new MyCustomRouteBaseThing())
```

... Or:

```
routes.Add(new Route("whatever/{possiblySomething}", new RouteValueDictionary {
        {"whatever", null}
    }, new MyImplementationOfIRouteHandler()));
```

... Etcetera, depending on your needs.

If you go with the `RouteBase` alternative for example, override `GetRouteData()`, `GetVirtualPath()` and whatnot. I'm not saying it's necessarily a better option than the accepted answer, I just don't see why routing should be deemed not viable. (What am I missing?)

**EDIT:** *At the time I wrote the above, the "accepted answer" was the one about URL rewriting posted by Tasos K, to whom the bounty was also rewarded. The accepted answer has since been reassigned.*

Answer (score 1):

I also don't know how this can be done using routing. But one way to achieve this is using URL rewriting instead. The whole process has a few steps and it is rather simple to make.

- **Applying the URL rewriting**

You add at the `Global.asax` the following function.

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Here you will get exception 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' when loading home page, handle accordingly
    string currentsegment = Request.Url.Segments[1]; 
    string RewritePath = "";

    if (IsTeam(currentsegment))
    {
        RewritePath = "~/team.aspx?team=" + currentsegment;
    }

    if (IsPlayer(currentsegment))
    {
        RewritePath = "~/player.aspx?player=" + currentsegment;
    }

    if (RewritePath != "") {
        // Adding all query string items to the new URL
        for (int I = 0; I <= Request.QueryString.Count - 1; I++)
        {
            RewritePath = RewritePath + "&" + Request.QueryString.Keys[I] + "=" + Request.QueryString[I];
        }
        Context.RewritePath(RewritePath);
    }
}
```

So if the URL has is `/some-title-here` you can get the `some-title-here` part using the `Request.Url.Segments` array.

Then based on that your code detects if this title is a team or a player. In any case you change internally the URL by calling the `Context.RewritePath(...)`.

One important thing is that you need to add all the query string items manually in order to pass them to your pages.

Also, inside your code the `Request.Url` will know the rewritten URL, not the original.

A quick way to test it is to implement the `IsTeam(...)` and `IsPlayer(...)` function as below. With only this code when hitting **/player-tasos** the `~/player.aspx?player=player-tasos` page loads and when hitting **/team-stackoverflow** the `~/team.aspx?team=team-stackoverflow` page loads.

```
private bool IsTeam(string segment)
{
    return segment.StartsWith("team");
}

private bool IsPlayer(string segment)
{
    return segment.StartsWith("player");
}
```

So far this approach works but it has one main issue. When there is a PostBack the URL changes to the one you have set in the `Context.RewritePath(...)`

- **Avoiding PostBack issue**

To avoid this issue you need to add to your projects two ASP.NET folders

1. App_Browsers
2. App_Code

In the App_Code folder you create a file `FormRewriter.cs` and add the following code (In my demo the root namespace is `WebFormsRewriting`)

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;

namespace WebFormsRewriting
{
    public class FormRewriterControlAdapter : System.Web.UI.Adapters.ControlAdapter
    {
        protected override void Render(System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter writer)
        {
            base.Render(new RewriteFormHtmlTextWriter(writer));
        }
    }

    public class RewriteFormHtmlTextWriter : System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter
    {

        public RewriteFormHtmlTextWriter(HtmlTextWriter writer)
            : base(writer)
        {
            this.InnerWriter = writer.InnerWriter;
        }

        public RewriteFormHtmlTextWriter(System.IO.TextWriter writer)
            : base(writer)
        {
            base.InnerWriter = writer;
        }

        public override void WriteAttribute(string name, string value, bool fEncode)
        {
            // If the attribute we are writing is the "action" attribute, and we are not on a sub-control, 
            // then replace the value to write with the raw URL of the request - which ensures that we'll
            // preserve the PathInfo value on postback scenarios
            if ((name == "action"))
            {
                HttpContext Context = default(HttpContext);
                Context = HttpContext.Current;

                if (Context.Items["ActionAlreadyWritten"] == null)
                {
                    // Because we are using the UrlRewriting.net HttpModule, we will use the 
                    // Request.RawUrl property within ASP.NET to retrieve the origional URL
                    // before it was re-written.  You'll want to change the line of code below
                    // if you use a different URL rewriting implementation.

                    value = Context.Request.RawUrl;

                    // Indicate that we've already rewritten the <form>'s action attribute to prevent
                    // us from rewriting a sub-control under the <form> control

                    Context.Items["ActionAlreadyWritten"] = true;
                }
            }

            base.WriteAttribute(name, value, fEncode);
        }
    }
}
```

In the App_Browsers folder you create a file `Form.browser` and add the following snippet. Note here to put the class name of the Adapter with its namespace.

```
<browsers>
    <browser refID="Default">
        <controlAdapters>
            <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm"
                     adapterType="WebFormsRewriting.FormRewriterControlAdapter" />
        </controlAdapters>
    </browser>
</browsers>
```

And that's it. Adding those two files will handle the PostBack issue. If you put the `FormRewriter.cs` outside the `App_Code` folder it will not work. Also those two folders **must be uploaded** to the production server.

I have used this approach for years in .NET 3.5 and .NET 4.0 without any problems. Today I also tested it in a .NET 4.5 Web Forms project and it works with no issues.

All of the above are based on a ScottGu's [article](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net) about the subject

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out... it would be much better NOT to use this route for both Players and Teams.

It would be preferable to setup two routes...

mysite.com/player/{PlayerName}

mysite.com/team/{TeamName}

In this way you can drive all "player" traffic to Player.aspx, and "team" traffic to Team.aspx, nice and easy.

However... If you really have to support a single route, I recommend that you add it as a third option, and use a 301 Redirect to one of the two above routes.

mysite.com/{PlayerOrTeamName} -> Route.aspx
Let Route.aspx handle requests that don't map to physical files.

Then your Route.aspx code needs to function as a 404 Error handler, but with a catch.. It will check the Players data and the Teams data for an exact match. If it finds one it should do a 301 permanent redirect to the correct /player/ or /team/ route.

Using...

```
string strCorrectURL = RouteTable.Routes.GetVirtualPath(null, "player", new RouteValueDictionary { { "Name", strValue }});

    Response.StatusCode = 301;
    Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
    Response.AddHeader("Location", strCorrectURL);
    Response.End();
```

This will give you the functionality of a single path, but tell search engines to index the more precise path.

You could skip the RouteTable altogether and just put this code into your default 404 handler.